# cocos2d animation keeps crashing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I am really really new to cocos2d and o.c programming, and I have been trying to figure out how the sprite animation works.
Due to the latest update I get a lot of old code which doesn't work anymore.

I have the following (a spriteheet with 3 sprites which i want to animate)

somehow it keeps crashing

this is in my init method

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache ] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"eno_glasses.plist" ];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"eno_glasses.png"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];

        _body = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"eno_glasses02.png"]];        
        [spriteSheet addChild:_body];
        _body.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);



        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eno_glasses0%d.png",i]];
            [animFrames addObject:frame];
        }
        CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:0.03f];
        CCAnimate* anime = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
        [self runAction:anime];
```

I know the images can be found because this works (and I can get the images from the plist 01,02,03)

am i forgetting a nil somewhere?

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache ] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"eno_glasses.plist" ];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"eno_glasses.png"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];

        _body = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"eno_glasses02.png"]];        
        [spriteSheet addChild:_body];
        _body.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);
```

Comment: also how do i make that sprite animate once, then wait a few seconds and animate again? use the tick constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use :

```
[_body runAction:anime];
```

as for repeating (assuming once)

```
id anime1=[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
id delay=[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2.0f];
id anime2=[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
id twice = [CCSequence actions:anime1,delay,anime2,nil];
[_body runAction:twice];
```

also, you may want to chose "eno_glasses01.png" as your start frame.